# Codeigniter router

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change Codeigniter router

```
ex. cms_aboutus_cate
```

to

```
controller
--cms
  --aboutus
    --cate.php
```

is there any other efficient way to achieve using routing or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['^cms_aboutus_cate$']  = "cms/aboutus/cate/index";
```

Is important that you set the index method.

I recommended you HMVC if you want modulate your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your url in config/routes.php file.
In your case, you can put:

$route['cms_aboutus_cate']  = 'cms/aboutus/cate';

So, the actual URL will be http://yourdomainname/cms/aboutus/cate but it will show in URL is this: http://yourdomainname/cms_aboutus_cate.

Reference:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html